# How to get the root path of a pylons website

Tags: pylons, path

I'm using pylons to build websites. I want to write some files to a directory under the root of the project, but I don't konw how can I get the root path(project path) in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   from pylons import config

   print config['pylons.paths']['root']
```